# Is there a way to use cheat codes like 'HESOYAM' on GTA San Andreas for iOS?

Tags: ios, cheats, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Is there a way to use [cheat codes](http://www.gtasanandreas.net/cheats/pc.php) like `HESOYAM` on GTA San Andreas for iOS *directly in the UI, without copying saved files*?

**Update**: Using a bluetooth keyboard doesn't work either.

Comment: after some googling it seems that: there IS a way to use cheats; but nobody knows how :(

Comment: I haven't played the game on iOS so I'm not sure, but on console versions you had to enter a combo on the controller to enable a cheat. Perhaps it is similar on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, copy files from PC folder to iOS folder after the cheat was used on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, by closely looking into the game executable for Android, I can tell that there was cheat support for the game during development. In fact, they had a cheat menu, with the names of many of the original cheat codes, as well as text versions of known cheat codes e.g. "ROCKETMAN" - which is the code for the cheat, not the name of the cheat - however, cheats whose official text codes aren't known are not mentioned by code, which tells me that War Drum Studios made an effort to keep unknown cheat codes unknown.

Parts of the cheat system have been rewritten and include system calls using the Android API to get keyboard input for them. However, since no one has reported getting cheats to work, I have to assume these features have been blocked off somehow, but not completely removed meaning they could be restored with some third-party work from the modding community.

Answer (score 0):

Take your savefile from your device, and put it onto your PC or Mac. Use this save game in the PC version of GTA San Andreas, use cheats there, then save and put the file back on your device.

Comment: See edit to original question.